# Can a jQuery ajaxSuccess function notice an AJAX event in another (javascript) file? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I've been trying to trigger a function after an ajax event has happened.
I've been told that even though the ajax event is happening in a different file (same server if that matters) and that file is javascript, not jquery, "Ajaxsuccess" will notice that an  ajax event happened and the function will be triggered:

**[Script A](http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.infinitescrollfortumblr.js)** (Line 100, javascript)

```
    function createHttpRequest() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest()
        } else {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')
                } catch (B) {
                    try {
                        return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
                    } catch (A) {
                        return null
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return null
            }
        }
    };
```

**[Script B](http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.syndex.js)** (Line 105, jQuery)

```
$('#debug').ajaxSuccess(function() {
     $(this).text('Triggered ajaxSuccess handler.'); 
});
```

Here is the page in question: http://syndex.me
(Aim is to have a fading in script work over all instances of .theImage div. but this doesnt matter for now so much, it's more just getting ajaxsuccess or *anything* to give me a cue that new images loaded onto the page dynamically. Then i can take it from there.

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery in both scripts?

Comment: I wish. Tumblr is nigh impossible to inifnite scroll. This is the only one out there that works, and it's hardcore javascript :-( I have to somehow make it talk to my own jquery scripts and i haven found out a way to do that yet.

Comment: how are you getting the images and how are you loading/want to load?

Answer (score 0):

You are attching it wrong. ajaxSuccess now need to be attached to document, see the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/).

> Additional Notes: As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery
>   global Ajax events, including those added with the .ajaxSuccess()
>   method, must be attached to document.